# GeoRegionValuePlot not using ColorFunction colours

Tags: plotting, bugs, color, geodesy

I have a custom `Blend` for use with `GeoRegionValuePlot`'s `ColorFunction` option.

```
colfoo = Blend[{{-1, Red}, {-0.1, Lighter@Pink}, {0, Yellow}, 
     {0.1, Lighter@Green}, {10, Darker@Green}}, #] &
```

The items to plot have two countries with value `0`; India and Russia.

```
vals = {Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"] -> -0.5, 
        Entity["Country", "India"] -> 0, 
        Entity["Country", "Canada"] -> 0.5, 
        Entity["Country", "Australia"] -> 1.75, 
        Entity["Country", "Russia"] -> 0, 
        Entity["Country", "Mexico"] -> 4.25};
```

I am expecting these to plot `Yellow` but they do not.

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[vals,
 GeoRange -> {{-60, 75}, {-130, 165}},
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 ColorFunction -> colfoo,
 GeoBackground -> None]
```

[image]

Why aren't they plotting `Yellow`?

Comment: Definitely a bug, you can boil it down to a 2-country example:  `GeoRegionValuePlot[{Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"] -> -1, 
  Entity["Country", "India"] -> 0},
 GeoRange -> {{-60, 75}, {-130, 165}},
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{{-1, Red}, {0, Yellow}}, #] &),
 GeoBackground -> None]` and they both come out red

Comment: @JasonB I've reported it to WRI. Let's see what they say.  I suppose I will have to plot it directly with `GeoGraphics` if it turns out it is a bug.

Comment: thanks for reporting it, I think this applies any time you have a small number of points and a custom color function.  I can think of a workaround that still uses `GeoRegionValuePlot`, will post tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

That's a funky bug. As JasonB points out in the comments, this can be reduced to a two-country example:

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[
 {
  Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"] -> -1,
  Entity["Country", "India"] -> 0
  }
 , GeoRange -> {{-60, 75}, {-130, 165}}
 , ColorFunctionScaling -> False
 , ColorFunction -> (Blend[{{-1, Red}, {0, Yellow}}, #] &)
 , GeoBackground -> Automatic
 , ImageSize -> 800
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

This appears to be caused by the presence of negative values. Shifting the range in the above example up from `{-1, 0}` to `{0, 1}` produces

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[
 {
  Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"] -> 0,
  Entity["Country", "India"] -> 1
  }
 , GeoRange -> {{-60, 75}, {-130, 165}}
 , ColorFunctionScaling -> False
 , ColorFunction -> (Blend[{{0, Red}, {1, Yellow}}, #] &)
 , GeoBackground -> Automatic
 , ImageSize -> 800
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Similarly, for your example, if you start with

```
vals = {
   Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"] -> -0.5
   , Entity["Country", "India"] -> 0
   , Entity["Country", "Canada"] -> 0.5
   , Entity["Country", "Australia"] -> 1.75
   , Entity["Country", "Russia"] -> 0
   , Entity["Country", "Mexico"] -> 4.25
   };

colfoo = Function[
  Blend[{
    {-1, Red},
    {-0.1, Lighter@Pink},
    {0, Yellow},
    {0.1, Lighter@Green},
    {10, Darker@Green}
    }, #]
  ]
```

and you shift them up using

```
vals /. {Rule[entity_Entity, x_] -> Rule[entity, x + 1]}
colfoo /. {{x_?NumericQ, color_} -> {x + 1, color}}
```

or just shifting your data range directly, you get

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[
 vals /. {Rule[entity_Entity, x_] -> Rule[entity, x + 1]}
 , GeoRange -> {{-60, 75}, {-130, 165}}
 , ColorFunctionScaling -> False
 , ColorFunction -> (colfoo /. {{x_?NumericQ, color_} -> {x + 1, color}})
 , GeoBackground -> Automatic
 , ImageSize -> 900
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

as you wanted.

Of course, having a workaround doesn't make it any less of a reportable bug, though. But this information should make it easier to pinpoint what's broken in the first place.

Comment: Ha ha, you beat me to it by 30 seconds!  I'll delete mine, but in your final bit of code you might consider adding `PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{colfoo, MinMax@vals[[All, 2]]}]` so as to keep the appearance of the original color scaling.

Comment: I'm beginning to think this is the result of some *clever* programming optimization by WRI that assigns the first colour in `Blend` to negative values rather than actually calling the `Blend` construct to improve performance.  Too clever, me'thinks.

Answer (score 0):

This bug seems to affect different versions differently, so more than one workaround is needed.  Here is another workaround that does **not** work in version 10.3.1, but it does work on other versions.

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[vals, GeoRange -> {{-60, 75}, {-130, 165}},
 GeoBackground -> None,
 ColorRules -> Flatten@Union[({# -> colfoo@#} & /@ vals[[All, 2]])],
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{colfoo, MinMax@vals[[All, 2]]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]